# Golang exec.Command prevents socket/internet access for launched service on Windows?

Tags: go

I am trying to use exec.Command().Output() to execute a 3rd party tool (SteamCMD) to download updates for a serverI run. When I run the commands normally through powershell, everything runs fine.

Example command I run:

`C:\SteamCMD\steamcmd.exe +force_install_dir "C:\gameserver" +login Mallachar +app_update 233780`

When I check the logs of the application, it works fine.

> [2022-01-05 23:13:23] Log session started
> [2022-01-05 23:13:23] [0,0] SetSteamID( [U:1:0] )
> [2022-01-05 23:13:23] CCMInterface::OnNetworkDeviceStateChange -- Saw device up (192.168.1.254)
> [2022-01-05 23:13:23] CCMInterface::OnNetworkDeviceStateChange -- Start connecting to Steam
> [2022-01-05 23:13:23] CCMInterface::OnNetworkDeviceStateChange -- Saw device up (192.168.1.254)
> [2022-01-05 23:13:23] CCMInterface::OnNetworkDeviceStateChange -- Start connecting to Steam
> [2022-01-05 23:13:23] CCMInterface::OnNetworkDeviceStateChange -- Saw device up (192.168.1.254)
> [2022-01-05 23:13:23] CCMInterface::OnNetworkDeviceStateChange -- Start connecting to Steam
> [2022-01-05 23:13:23] [0,0] SetSteamID( [U:1:879488788] )
> [2022-01-05 23:13:23] [0,0] SetSteamID( [U:1:879488788] )
> [2022-01-05 23:13:23] [0,0] Server says 50% of connections should be websockets, we rolled 41 - using WebSockets as default.

However, when I run this through Golang, It doesn't work

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

const armA3ServerID string = "+app_update 233780"

func steamSession(configData Server, steamCMDUser string, steamCMDPass string) {
    var steamCMDCommand strings.Builder
    steamCMDCommand.WriteString("+force_install_dir \"" + configData.Arma3path + "\" ")
    steamCMDCommand.WriteString("+login " + steamCMDUser + " " + steamCMDPass + " ")
    steamCMDCommand.WriteString(armA3ServerID)

    steamCMDCommand.WriteString(" +quit")

    out, err := exec.Command(configData.Steamcmdpath+"steamcmd.exe", steamCMDCommand.String()).Output()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error Is", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(out))
}
```

The command hangs because of networking issues, and I get this log output

> [2022-01-05 23:35:59] Log session started
> [2022-01-05 23:35:59] [0,0] SetSteamID( [U:1:0] )
> [2022-01-05 23:35:59] CCMInterface::OnNetworkDeviceStateChange -- Saw device up (192.168.1.254)
> [2022-01-05 23:35:59] CCMInterface::OnNetworkDeviceStateChange -- Start connecting to Steam
> [2022-01-05 23:35:59] CCMInterface::OnNetworkDeviceStateChange -- Saw device up (192.168.1.254)
> [2022-01-05 23:35:59] CCMInterface::OnNetworkDeviceStateChange -- Start connecting to Steam
> [2022-01-05 23:35:59] CCMInterface::OnNetworkDeviceStateChange -- Saw device up (192.168.1.254)
> [2022-01-05 23:35:59] CCMInterface::OnNetworkDeviceStateChange -- Start connecting to Steam
> [2022-01-05 23:35:59] IPv6 HTTP connectivity test (ipv6check-http.steamcontent.com / 0.0.0.0:80 (0.0.0.0:80)) - TIMEOUT
> [2022-01-05 23:35:59] IPv6 UDP connectivity test (ipv6check-udp.steamcontent.com) - FAILED, no addresses resolved

When I terminate the background instance of the steamcmd running, my GoLang program prints out the output which showed it did tried to execute, but just hung at the connection part.

[image]

So As far as I can tell, it seems like when I used exec.Command, the services I launch with it do not have internet/socket access? I tried running as admin, but didn't seem to fix anything. Not sure if maybe there is a step I am missing or something I need to change flag wise.

So the command does run, the backend application runs, but it fails to resolve the address/make a connection. So seems like my command itself is not the issue, but something with GoLang exec.Command?

Comment: Edit the question to show the correct code. The way it is included, it is not valid Go code.

Comment: updated with new code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a single argument to the command, the concatenation of all the arguments. Try this instead:

```
   out, err := exec.Command(
     configData.Steamcmdpath+"steamcmd.exe",
     "+force_install_dir", configData.Arma3path,
     "+login ",steamCMDUser,steamCMDPass,
      "+app_update", "233780",
     "+quit",
  ).Output()
```

Comment: Mallachar, the command line in windows (or the equivalent in posix) ends up doing the same thing, once it splits on spaces.

Comment: So I get this to an extent, but I am confused as to why the error I am getting is the fact that DNS cant resolve?

Comment: It is likely that the executable somehow interprets the arguments as some sort of a network address or URL.

Comment: So one of the challenges I run into then is the amount of arguments is eventually going to be dynamically sized. One of the things I am hoping to do is feed it a list of "mods" to also download, defined by a YAML file, so I had something like this.

```const workshopSTR string = " +workshop_download_item 107410 "
 for _, workshopID := range configData.Modules {
  steamCMDCommand.WriteString(workshopSTR + strconv.Itoa(workshopID))
 }

```
to eventually give me something that looks like

Comment: ```+app_update 233780 +workshop_download_item 107410 313041182 +workshop_download_item 107410 450814997 +workshop_download_item 107410 463939057 +workshop_download_item 107410 583496184 +workshop_download_item 107410 583544987 +workshop_download_item 107410 632435682 +workshop_download_item 107410 667709746 +workshop_download_item 107410 735566597 +workshop_download_item 107410 773125288 +workshop_download_item 107410 773131200 +workshop_download_item 107410 782415569 +workshop_download_item 107410 843425103 +quit```

Comment: Put them all in a slice of strings, then call Exec with args...

Comment: Alright I will give that a shot, thank you very much.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very much